# How do I use google API within perl CGI script?

Tags: javascript, perl, cgi, google-api

The google API example shows that you should have the javascript within the head tag but I am using perl module CGI and in there they suggest that you use "print header;" instead of writting out your headers explicitly.

So if I want to use the perl CGI module and the google API javascript what is the correct way to do this?

I tried writing out the header explicitly but It seemed like the perl module really wanted me to use the header method. It seems like this would be a common use case but I looked around the web for some examples of this and I could not find one. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did it work when you wrote out the header explicitly? That's the important thing.

Comment: It did not work when I wrote out the header explicitly but I do not have access to the server log right now. When I get back home I will report what the error said.

Comment: After a little bit of playing with it I find my main issue was a very newbee problem where my first line was not the "Content-Type: text/html\n\n". So I am not using CGI very much at all and it seems to be working well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just ignore the CGI documentation and print your own HTML head section with the `<script>` section.

By the way, the `header` function in CGI prints the HTTP header, not the HTML header. The html header is produced by a function [`start_html`](http://search.cpan.org/~lds/CGI.pm-3.49/lib/CGI.pm#CREATING_THE_HTML_DOCUMENT_HEADER). But you do not need to use CGI's built-in function. CGI output is supposed to look like the following (without the # parts):

```
Content-Type: text/html                   # HTTP HEADER

<html>                                    # HTML HEADER
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">           # JavaScript
...
</script>
</head>
...
```

Comment: Should I use the other functions in the CGI module or just write out everything myself? Seems like the CGI module is just getting in the way.

Comment: @stephenmm: I wouldn't recommend using the HTML generation routines in CGI.pm. If you have a lot of HTML generation to do, think about using the Template Toolkit (Template module). Otherwise, just use print statements and heredocs.